# Source code breadcrumbs in Vim

Tags: eclipse, vim, ctags, cscope

Eclipse has a "breadcrumbs" feature: a little bar that shows which part of the code tree you are now in, e.g. `src/java/main > org.foo.bar > AbstractFactoryFactory > InnerDefaultFactory > SomeNeatInnerRunnable > doEverything`.

Does Vim has something similar, supposedly some script based on ctags / cscope?

Answer (score 1):

I am only aware of the [CTX plug-in](http://chouser.n01se.net/ctx/) for C code.